# Deprecating Wordpress URL from Google, promoting custom domain

Tags: search, domain-mapping, google-search, search-engines

I'm hosting a simple set of information pages at `mysite.wordpress.com` (anonymized for simplicity). I've purchased a domain -- `www.mysite.com` -- and have made it my primary domain for `mysite.wordpress.com`. Redirection works correctly from all pages, so I know that's done right. When I search for `mysite` in Google, however, the index page still shows the old link:

```
Search Result for "my site".
About 398,000 results (0.49 seconds) 

MySite | MySite, the best site out there!
mysite.wordpress.com/         <-- Wrong link! Should be mysite.com

Contact Info | MySite 
mysite.com/contact-info/      <-- Expected link

About Us | MySite
mysite.com/about/             <-- Expected link
```

Attempts to go to `mysite.wordpress.com`  will redirect the user to `mysite.com`, which is good, but it does look unprofessional. How might I request/encourage Google to display `mysite.com` for my index page and *not* (hopefully never!) `mysite.wordpress.com`?

Comment: It sounds like you've done the WordPress bit right as the site is working as you want, so this is a Google question really.

Comment: I assumed so. I figured, however, that other WordPress users might have had similar experiences, so this seemed the natural place to ask as a start. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was simply a matter of waiting: the less trafficked pages updated their addresses quickly and the more trafficked pages (e.g., the home page) took longer to be update in Google search results. Other users with more heavily trafficked sites might wish to refer to [this article on demoting site links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) to achieve results more quickly, but, for the rest of us, all that is required seems to be patience. :)